# will db monitoring with pg_stat/pg_statio slow down my other queries?

Tags: database, postgresql, monitoring, pg-stat-statements

I recently built a database monitoring plugin for postgresql that queries the pg_stat and pg_statio tables in postgresql.  I want to understand/test how my plugin might affect my database but fear that if i just turned my plugin on my database, my database may crash and burn...  I was hoping that someone could suggest some testing methods or answer some of my questions/concerns below:

1) I was wondering if these monitoring queries would cause my other non-monitoring queries (which I assume also need to write to the pg_statio tables to update these statistics) to lock up.

2) Is there a way for me to capture database traffic on a postgresql database table so I can maybe replay this traffic on a copy of the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will db monitoring with pg_stat/pg_statio slow down my other queries?

No. Not significantly, anyway.

> 1) I was wondering if these monitoring queries would cause my other non-monitoring queries (which I assume also need to write to the pg_statio tables to update these statistics) to lock up.

No. In PostgreSQL reads do not block writes.

> 2) Is there a way for me to capture database traffic on a postgresql database table so I can maybe replay this traffic on a copy of the database?

Not easily, at the present time.

You can record statements and parameters in the logs, along with a `log_line_prefix` that lets you reassemble them into transactions and sessions. It'll be painful to parse the logs for this though. Also, IIRC super-long statements can be truncated.

You can in PostgreSQL 9.4 extract the *rows changed* using logical decoding, but that doesn't tell you which statements changed them, and it doesn't let you reproduce the load. Replaying the change stream is a very different load to creating it in the first place.

Tools like `pg_stat_statements` can help a bit, but won't give you a verbatim stream of changes.